# i can't print the result in the file

Tags: c#

it hit me an error in this line:foreach(var textBox in textBoxes).it doesn't recognise
the:textBoxes.i try to write as TextBox and hits me again an error.i have the Visual C# 2010 Express edition

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    private TextBox[] TextBoxes = {textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5, textBox6};

    private List<string> storeItems = new List<string>();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var buffer = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(var textBox in textBoxes)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
        {
            textBox.BackColor = Color.FromName("LightSalmon");
            MessageBox.Show("This item cannot be left blank");
            textBox.Focus();
            return;
        }
        textBox.BackColor = Colors.FromName("Window");
        buffer.Append(textBox.Text);
    }

    var result = buffer.ToString();
    storeItems.Add(result);
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\v\Desktop\text.txt", Environment.NewLine + result);
}
```

Comment: What kind of error did it “hit” you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to create fields inside a constructor. You can't do that, do something like this instead:

```
private TextBox[] TextBoxes = {textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5, textBox6};

private List<string> storeItems = new List<string>();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

And it also looks like you have the capitalization wrong. `TextBoxes` is different from `textBoxes` in C#.

Answer (score 1):

This line is placed in the wrong place.

```
private TextBox[] TextBoxes = {textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5, textBox6};
```

Your variable TextBox is recognized only in the constructor. You have to place it in the class, not in a method of the class.

For example after this line:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
```

Or even like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    private TextBox[] TextBoxes = {textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5, textBox6};

    private List<string> storeItems = new List<string>();
}
private TextBox[] TextBoxes = {textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5, textBox6};
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
```

Edit: As Svick said, this line too is not in the right place:

```
private List<string> storeItems = new List<string>();
```

Follow the same rule for it.

Comment: It's not recognized even in the constructor. Local variables can't be `private`.

Comment: Yes, you are true indeed, I found it strange to write private within the constructor

Answer (score -1):

Could it be that your array `TextBoxes` is capitalized while you're trying to foreach through `textBoxes`?